# Migrating from Getx to SharedPreferences and RiverPod

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, riverpod

Does anyone know how to migrate from Getx to SharedPreferences and Riverpod?

I use Getx when I declare varaible. E.g. `var name = ''.obs;`.
Is there a way to migrate to Riverpod?

Also, I use GetStorage to store key and value pair.
Is there a way to migrate to SharedPreferences without using future builder ?

I am sorry if my question is stupid or incorrect. Having difficulty with my assignment migrating from Getx to SharedPreferences and RiverPod.

If you could help, thanks a lot.

I am trying to use SharedPreferences and RiverPod.

Comment: what your reason for migrating GetX to SharedPreferences and RiverPod?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option is to replace all `.obs` with `StateProvider`:

```dart
var name = ''.obs;

// now
final nameProvider = StateProvider((_) => '');
```

In the widget it will look like this:

```dart
return Center(child: Obx(() => Text("Your name: $name"));

// now
return Center(
  child: Consumer(
    builder: (context, ref, child) {
      final name = ref.watch(nameProvider);
      return Text("Your name: $name"));
    },
  ),
);
```

As for using SharedPreferences, there are several ways. One of them looks like this:

```dart
final sharedPreferencesProvider = Provider<SharedPreferences>((_) {
  return throw UnimplementedError();
});

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  return runApp(ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      sharedPreferencesProvider.overrideWithValue(prefs),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

And now you will be able to use your `prefs` instance via `sharedPreferencesProvider` anywhere in the code where there is a `Ref ref`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are my life saver!! I will give it a try.